# Lowering the quality of pdf generated by epstopdf or convert to another image format like jpg

Tags: eps, epstopdf

Is there a package to convert epstojpg or some other low quality image format, just like there is epstopdf for pdf?

Or is there any setting i can use on epstopdf to reduce the image quality so i can have a faster pdf file?

Comment: Welcome to Tex.Exchange! If you receive useful answers, consider to accept one [https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers].

Comment: Hi and welcome, the pdf will be generated only once and later the image is included. To my knowledge, theere shouldn't be a real difference in speed. If speed is an issue, you should consider other methods, like comenting out parts of the document using `input`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In windows, try this software:

1. http://download.cnet.com/Free-EPS-To-JPG-Converter/3000-2192_4-76086793.html
2. http://www.softpedia.com/get/Multimedia/Graphic/Image-Convertors/Free-EPS-To-JPG-Converter.shtml

> In Linux: (ubuntu)

Install imagemagick:

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```

Then, to convert:

```
convert foo.eps foo.jpg
```

to resize:

```
convert -resize 1024X768 source.png dest.jpg
```

> More specific info on other linux versions or related posts:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=eps+to+jpg
2. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1444695
3. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7583821/how-to-convert-a-eps-file-to-a-high-quality-1024x1024-jpg

Comment: i am using window, i don't understand sudo. I want to find a package that can do this internally in Latex

Comment: the converter is named "ImageMagick".  the web site from which it can be obtained is http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php.

Comment: This is wrong. The instructions marked 'For Linux' will work only on certain distros. Neither of the distros I use would recognise those commands. `apt-get` is a distribution-specific command. It will work only for distros which use that specific package manager. Moreover, whether or not `imagemagick` is the correct name of the package also depends on your distro. Finally, not all Linux distros have `sudo` available by default.

Comment: @user13892 see the update and consider to accept this answer to your question